# Initial Password change for Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc

I'm pretty new to spring and wondered if anyone can help me,

I need to be able to have a user forced to change their password on their first login attempt i have seen other posts which explain it roughly but have little knowledge on how to implement